# can I use asset catalog to manage image other than launch image and app icon?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, asset-catalog

How can I use asset catalog to define images other than launch image and app icon.
I have added new image set but it is not displaying the right image on different device resolutions. I had seen the content json generated for new image set . I found this.

```
{
    "orientation" : "landscape",
    "idiom" : "ipad",
    "extent" : "full-screen",
    "minimum-system-version" : "7.0",
    "filename" : "Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png",
    "scale" : "2x"
}
```

Basic concern is screen size not the os version. why minimum os version is there ? I need screen size instead. Please help me If I am going in wrong direction.

Comment: I will have to create multiple xib files for different sizes. If os does not picks appropriate image from image set. android os gives this flexibility does iOs have this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set other images in the app by asset catalog as well. This is the [Apple Help for Asset Catalog.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html)